# check the same value on different arrays or variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have 2 variables of equal value:

```
    $word1 = 'a, b, c, d';
    $word2 = 'b, c, d, a';
```

I want to check whether the two variables have exactly the same value. How to check it?

Comment: explode, sort, implode, compare

Comment: that's help me, thanks but can you tell me about coding for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [array_dif()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Example

```
<?php

$word1 = 'a, b, c, d';
$word2 = 'b, c, d, a';

$array1 = explode(', ', $word1);
$array2 = explode(', ', $word2);
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);

?>
```

[Live example](http://codepad.org/FpuEqRwP)

Comment: So no difference means same arrays ;)

Answer (score 0):

using this code you have to get same value in array

```
 <?php

 $word1 =array('a, b, c, d');
 $word2 =array('b, c, d, a');
 $data = array_intersect($word1, $word2);

  ?>
```

Comment: <?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>

Comment: output: Array
(
    [1] => blue
)